# Combining ViewModels With ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am making a simple App which holds a list of timers and allows the user to scroll between these timers via ViewPager. Android Architecture Component principles are in effect here: the ViewModel holds the state of the app, and Fragments/Activities just handle UI interactions.

In this case, a custom ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter has been made. My question is, **what is the best way to have the ViewPager/adapter respond to changes in the ViewModel?**

The current code below works fine, but is there a better way to do this? Currently, both the ViewPager and Adapter require reference to the ViewModel and this feels contrary to what MVVM should implement.

*ViewPager*

```
    class VerticalTimerViewPager(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): ViewPager(context, attributeSet){

    var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel?=null

    init {
        setPageTransformer(true, VerticalPageTransformer())
    }


    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        ev ?: return false
        val intercepted =  super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev))
            swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev)
        return intercepted
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        homeViewModel ?: throwNoViewModelException()
        when(ev?.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> homeViewModel?.onSwipeDown()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> homeViewModel?.onSwipeUp()
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev ?: return false))
    }

    private fun swapXYOnMotionEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent): MotionEvent{
        with(motionEvent){
            val newX = (y/height)*width
            val newY = (x/width) * height
            setLocation(newX, newY)
        }
        return motionEvent
    }

    private fun throwNoViewModelException():Boolean{
        throw RuntimeException("${this.javaClass.simpleName}: HomeViewModel must be set by setting the variable homeViewModel")
    }
}
```

*FragmentStatePagerAdapter*

```
 class VerticalTimerViewPager(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): ViewPager(context, attributeSet){

    var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel?=null

    init {
        setPageTransformer(true, VerticalPageTransformer())
    }


    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        ev ?: return false
        val intercepted =  super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev))
            swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev)
        return intercepted
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        homeViewModel ?: throwNoViewModelException()
        when(ev?.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> homeViewModel?.onSwipeDown()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> homeViewModel?.onSwipeUp()
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev ?: return false))
    }

    private fun swapXYOnMotionEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent): MotionEvent{
        with(motionEvent){
            val newX = (y/height)*width
            val newY = (x/width) * height
            setLocation(newX, newY)
        }
        return motionEvent
    }

    private fun throwNoViewModelException():Boolean{
        throw RuntimeException("${this.javaClass.simpleName}: HomeViewModel must be set by setting the variable homeViewModel")
    }
}
```

*Instantiation Method called in Activity onCreate()*

```
    private fun setupPagerAdapter() {
    val pagerAdapter = TimerSlidePagerAdapter(viewModel = viewModel, fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager)
    with(pager){
        adapter = pagerAdapter
        homeViewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using **`ViewModel`** to communicate for `onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?)` from your **adapter** & **view pager**, if you want to make your adapter & view pager independent form ViewModel i would suggest you following way:

1. Make one interface having methods `onSwipeDown()` & `onSwipeUp()` *(or make any N numbers of method you want to have for ViewModel)*
2. Take this interface object instead of `ViewModel` in your view pager & adapter.
3. Implement this interface to your `ViewModel` *(which will expose methods of interface in ViewModel)*.
4. Cast your interface to `ViewModel` where you're passing ViewModel to adapter and view pager.

*Voila! you've made your adapter & view pager independent to ViewModel's direct reference.*

Comment: Thank you Jeel. I used the general idea of what you suggested, but diverged in how to implement the interface. Out of preference, I'm using the Activity to implement the interface, and talk to the ViewModel. In addition, the ViewPager now accepts a list of Objects. When the dataset changes, we will just reset the adapter. Your answer will be marked as the solution, but I will post my solution code anyway. Thank you for your time. Your suggestion got me in the right mindset.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer from Jeel Vankhede was marked as a solution and implemented. For future reference, the solution code will be pasted below to show the specifics of how the ViewPager and Adapter were successfully made independent of the ViewModel:

---

**ViewPager:**
notice we now have an Interface object. When the ViewPager is swiped, if there is no interface object, an exception is thrown.

```
//Overriding default touch events and swapping x/y coordinates prior to handling
class VerticalTimerViewPager(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): ViewPager(context, attributeSet){

    var timerViewPagerEventListener: TimerViewPagerEvent? = null

    init {
        setPageTransformer(true, VerticalPageTransformer())
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        ev ?: return false
        val intercepted =  super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev))
            swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev)
        return intercepted
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        timerViewPagerEventListener ?: throwInterfaceExeption()
        when(ev?.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->  timerViewPagerEventListener?.onViewPagerSwipeDown()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->    timerViewPagerEventListener?.onViewPagerSwipeUp()
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXYOnMotionEvent(ev ?: return false))
    }

    private fun throwInterfaceExeption():Boolean {
        throw RuntimeException("${this.javaClass.simpleName}: Parent Activity must implement TimerViewPagerEvent interface" )
    }

    private fun swapXYOnMotionEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent): MotionEvent{
        with(motionEvent){
            val newX = (y/height)*width
            val newY = (x/width) * height
            setLocation(newX, newY)
        }
        return motionEvent
    }

    interface TimerViewPagerEvent{
        fun onViewPagerSwipeUp()
        fun onViewPagerSwipeDown()
    }
}
```

---

**Adapter:** Now takes a list of objects (Timers in this case)

```
class TimerSlidePagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, private val timers: List<TimerEntity>?):
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager){

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        if (count > 0) {
            return makeTimerFragment(position)
        }
        return NoDataFragment()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int = timers?.size ?: 0

    //Internal Functions
    private fun makeTimerFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        timers ?: return NoDataFragment()
        val timeInMS = timers[position].timeInMS
        return if (timeInMS > 0) {
            TimerFragment.newInstance(timeInMS)
        } else {
            NoDataFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity Implementation:**

```
    private fun setupPagerAdapter() {
        val pagerAdapter = TimerSlidePagerAdapter(
                fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
                timers = viewModel?.timers?.value)

        with(pager){
            adapter = pagerAdapter
            timerViewPagerEventListener = this@MainActivity
        }
    }

private fun observeTimers(){
    viewModel.timers.observe(this, Observer {timerList->
        timerList ?: Log.e(this.javaClass.simpleName, "List of timers is null")
                .also {return@Observer}
        setupPagerAdapter()
    })
}
```

Comment: In your TimerSlidePagerAdapater, how did you handle override fun instantiateItem?  I've noticed that that is called when the device is rotated and getItem is not.